# Flash is persisted after redirect, but regular assign is not

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

To test the issue, I've created a new phoenix project (v1.2.1), and simply did this:

```
defmodule Playground.PageController do
  use Playground.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> assign(:test, "test works")
    |> put_flash(:info, "information")
    |> redirect(to: "/sub")
  end

  def sub(conn, _) do
    conn
    |> render("index.html")
  end
end
```

Once I request `:index` through `"/"`, I get redirected to `:sub` through `"/sub"`. For some reason, within the eex template, the flash added before the redirect is available, but the assign is not. I've looked at the Plug and Phoenix code, and can't really understand why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've looked at the Plug and Phoenix code, and can't really understand why?

"flash" values in Phoenix are actually stored using Plug's `put_session`, just before the response is sent and the response is an HTTP redirect. If it's not, the current flash value is deleted:

```
def fetch_flash(conn, _opts \\ []) do
  flash = get_session(conn, "phoenix_flash") || %{}
  conn  = persist_flash(conn, flash)

  register_before_send conn, fn conn ->
    flash = conn.private.phoenix_flash

    cond do
      map_size(flash) == 0 ->
        conn
      conn.status in 300..308 ->
        put_session(conn, "phoenix_flash", flash)
      true ->
        delete_session(conn, "phoenix_flash")
    end
  end
end
```

[Source](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/aa997350f917a6437a059f265a5647cd22625219/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L966-L985)

Assigns on the other hand are stored directly in the `conn` struct and are only available for the current request/response. If you want to store something and access it in the next request, you can use [`Plug.Conn.put_session/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_session/3). Something like this:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  conn
  |> put_session(:test, "test works")
  |> put_flash(:info, "information")
  |> redirect(to: "/sub")
end

def sub(conn, _) do
  test = get_session(conn, :test)
  conn
  |> assign(:test, test)
  |> render("index.html")
end
```